# Set Pagination with Toolbar in frontend .html file

Tags: magento-1.9

I don't have any idea to put pagination. I have to display all order commission details. this is the first time for me to create the front end so no idea how to create it. what are the files needed? pagination with the toolbar.

Comment: have you use any custom extension for the order commission details?

Comment: no i am not use any extension.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used this for product collections but you can give it a try. In the block behind your list PHTML file add the following method

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();

    $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
    $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(15=>15));
    $pager->setCollection($your_collection);

    $this->setChild('pager', $pager);

    return $this;
}
```

and add the following in your template file

```
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
```

other solution if any problem raises.

> ```
> $this->getPagerHtml() in catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml means you are trying to call getPagerHtml() method of class
> ```
>
> Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
>       whereas $this->getPagerHtml() in catalog/product/list.phtml means you are trying to call getPagerHtml() method of class
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List where it is not present.
>       If you want to call $this->getPagerHtml() in list.phtml then first you need to create object of class
>   Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar in list.phtml

Example :

> ```
> $object = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar();
> $object->getPagerHtml();
> ```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: also check link :- http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/catalog/pagination.html

Comment: could u tell me. the file structure, which files should be edited, my requirement is when the customer is logged in to the site their commission order details should be shown. with pagination and tool bar

Comment: you have to only add <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?> this will automatically add in .phtml file where you want.

Answer (score 0):

To get follow this:

```
echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'order_id')
          ->setCollection($collection)
          ->toHtml();
```

by `order_id` it takes pagination

Comment: It is working. I hope it will help someone

Comment: the above code should place where you need pagination

Answer (score -1):

**For Magento 2.3.x above**

Add this into your **Pager.php** block file

**VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Frontend\Pager**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Frontend\Pager;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Pager extends Template
{
    protected $modalFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ..........................................
        ..........................................
        \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\YourModalName $modalFactory,
        ..........................................
        ..........................................
    ) {
        ..........................................
        ..........................................
        $this->modalFactory = $modalFactory;
        ..........................................
        ..........................................
    }
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Pager Show'));
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $page_size = [];
        $page_size[5] = 5;
        $page_size[10] = 10;
        $page_size[15] = 15;
        $pager_collection = $this->getPager();
        if ($this->getPager()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager::class,
                'my.custom.pager'
            )
                ->setAvailableLimit($page_size)
                ->setShowPerPage(true)
                ->setCollection($pager_collection);
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getPager()->load();
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
    public function getPager()
    {
        $page = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
        
        $pageSize = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 5;

        $collection = $this->modalFactory->getCollection();
        $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $collection->setCurPage($page);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Add this into your **pager.phtml** file

**VendoreName\ModuleName\view\frontend\templates**

```
.................................................................
.................................................................
.................................................................
    <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
            <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom">
                <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
            </div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

And finally add into your layout file

```
<block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Frontend\Pager\Pager" name="pager_demo" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::pager.phtml" cacheable="false">
```

Run magento command

```
php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f 

php bin/magento c:c
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Question was about M1.

Comment: @sv3n in my opinion though it's m1 question but M2 answer add value to it, I am not sure, let's ask question in meta and let's check community opinion