# Custom collection pager is not shown in magento 2

Tags: magento2, pager

Custom collection pager is not shown in Magento 2

status.php

```
 public function getProduct()
    {       
        //get values of current page
        $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
        //get values of current limit
        $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'):20;
        
        $productItems =  $this->productCollectionFactory->create();   
        $productItems->addAttributeToSelect('name'); 
        $productItems->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $productItems->setCurPage($page);

        return $productItems;
    }

 protected function _prepareLayout()
 {

    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Low Stock Products'));

    if ($this->getProduct()) {
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
            'lowstocknotification.status.pager'
        )->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15,20=>20))
            ->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection(
            $this->getProduct()
        );
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getProduct()->load();
    }
    return $this;
}


public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}
```

stockgrid.phtml

```
<?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?> 
<div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom">
<?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?>
</div> 
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><span><?php echo __('No any record.'); ?></span></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304270/82670